# react-native-maps: UrlTile and Polyline - zIndex/Overlaying not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps`. I use the `<MapView.UrlTile/>` and on top I am trying to visualize a `<MapView.Polyline />`. However, the `Polyline` is not visible. It lays under the passed `URL Template`. I can tell that, because when I zoom and pinch, I see the `Polyline` with the underlaying standard base map (on `Android` its `google maps`) for a brief time of rendering/loading the map.
With markers, this problem does not occur.

Any ideas how I get the `Polyline` on top of the `URL Template`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `zIndex` on `PolyLine` defaults to *0* while the `Tiles zIndex` defaults to -1 https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1181.
However, that brings the `PolyLine` not into the foreground.

Setting the `zIndex` of the `Tiles` to **negative** while setting the `zIndex` of the Polyline to something **positive** solves the problem.